# Remote System Development Eclipse - Build, Debug and Run from remote Linux machine

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging

I have the following:

1) Windows machine with Eclipse CDT (Currently Luna v4.4.1)
2) A Linux machine that has the repository with code and the Linux GCC, make etc..

I want to connect to the Linux via Remote System Explorer in Eclipse, edit, build, debug and run all from the Windows machine in Eclipse.

I have been successful in setting up the SSH connection and in the project explorer, I can access the remote repository and edit the code.

The issue I am having is building, debugging and running it.

How can I let eclipse know I want to compile it remotely? The Project -> Build functionality is blocked out when attempting for the remote repository. It only allows it for local repo's. But I already have an SSH connection.. Is there not a way for it to know that I want to use the remote GCC too?

Also, for debugging, in the Debug configuration it seems to want a local version of the build, even though I selected remote debugging.

Sorry I don't have any error logging to report as i'm just struggling on the first bit of how I go about doing the remote build in the IDE.

Maybe this is not possible?

Comment: Are you using [this approach](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.rdt.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fgettingstarted%2Fcreating_a_remote_project.html)?